# How to use <Omit> and generic types in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to generalise a service layer in an API in typescript using a base Data Transfer Object.

To not have to re-write the types definition i'm using `<Omit>`.
However, it raises some typescript errors that i am not able to understand.

For instance, i do not understand why the following code:

```js
type A = { a: string };
function test<T extends A>(ot: Omit<T, "a">): T {
  return {
    ...ot,
    a: "a",
  };
}
```

is raising the following error:

> Type 'Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "a">> & { a: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "a">> & { a: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'A'.

I understand why

```js
function test<T extends string>():T {return "This is not specific enough!"}
```

does not work, but in the case above we are just defining dynamically the omitted field, we are not forgetting any constraint. What am i getting wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer your version to something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Gm3ZqN)?

Comment: That's a good workaround, however in my case the function is a member of a class and that generic is used in the class like this:
`class BaseService<Model> { function create(o: <Omit Model, "id">): Model`

now... maybe i could define my `Model` without the id everywhere and use your trick for all of the functions. It's just counter-intuitive

Answer (score 1):

Your function fails type-checking because it is not type-safe. The error message explains: your function returns something which *"is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'A'."*

For example, `type Foo = {a: 'foo'}` is also a sub-type of the constraint `A`. If your function is called like `test<Foo>(obj)`, then it promises to return something of type `Foo`, but the actual return value is not assignable to the type `Foo`.

Comment: Of course... I was seing this when returning a variable but not when it's in the object.
Now i am a bit struggling to understand how i can express that concept.
Is there a way to enforce a type to be "less specific" on that particular field?
The real life usecase there is that i want all my objects to have an "id" that is generated on the creation of the object in a function like:
`create(Omit<Model, "id">) => Model`
I want to be able to write the types `Model` only once and not have to write `UpdateModel` `CreateModel` `FullModel` etc

Comment: Actually... why does this work then ? `type A = {"id": string}` and `function test<T extends A>(a: T): A {
    a.id = "fsafsdf"; // what if T = {a: "SPECIFIC"} ?
    return a;
}`

Comment: can't edit the comment above anymore, but there's a typo the good function definition is: `test<T extends A>(a: T): T`

Comment: That's an example of unsound behaviour which Typescript does allow; quoting from [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness), *"TypeScript’s type system allows certain operations that can’t be known at compile-time to be safe. [...] The places where TypeScript allows unsound behavior were carefully considered, and throughout this document we’ll explain where these happen and the motivating scenarios behind them."* So if you are curious about the rationale, an explanation might be found there.