# How to solve `T` could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've seen some other questions and answers on this topic, but none seems to be sufficiently related to my problem (or maybe I lack the abstract thinking skills necessary to draw a relation).

I'm trying to do what I hoped was a simple operation in TypeScript

```
type Props = {
  prop1: number;
  prop2: number;
}

type WithoutProp1<T extends Props> = Omit<T, "prop1">;

function rebuildProps<T extends Props>(
  withoutIt: WithoutProp1<T>,
  prop1: number,
): T {
  return {
    ...withoutIt,
    prop1,
  }
}
```

This seems very intuitive to me: if I remove a property from a type and add it back, I get the same type.

However it's now working. Could someone explain to me:

- How can I fix it for this usecase? i.e. receiving a type derived from another without one property and the property, and then merge them to return an object of the original type (the one the input was derived from)
- Is this wrong or is it just that TypeScript can't do it that way? Can someone give me an example of a case where this would break if it were accepted by the compiler?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/65452763/2887218 and tell me if your question is or is not a duplicate of that one.  If not, you should [edit] the question to make the difference clear.

Comment: See [this example](https://tsplay.dev/wjknkN) for the analogous problem from the other question.  Really such things should probably be done like [this](https://tsplay.dev/we4pXW) where the compiler computes the output type.

Comment: You're right, this is definitely a duplicate of that one. Took me a while but I finally undestood your example, I'm flagging this as duplicate